# R package code coverage with test_that and readline()

Tags: r, codecov

Good morning,
I'm building an R package and trying to get code coverage (via codecov) as high as possible. But, I'm struggling to use test_that when the function requires input via readline(). Here is a simplified function using readline() in a similar way to mine.

```
fun<-function(){
  y<-as.numeric(readline((prompt="Enter a number: ")))
  res<-2*y
  res
}
```

Any way to use `test_that()` with this function without having to manually input a number everytime this runs? Like, setting up a default input number only for the test?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `?readline()`:

> This [function] can only be used in an interactive session.

In a case like this I would probably rewrite my function to something like this:

```r
fun <- function(y = readline(prompt = "Enter a number: ")) {
  y <- as.numeric(y)
  res <- 2 * y
  res
}
```

When used interactively it works just the same, but when you want to test the function you can do so programmatically, for example:

```r
expect_equal(
  fun(y = 10),
  20
)
```

Other alternatives is to include some options in your package or an environment variable that tells your code that you are in testing mode, and alters the behavior of `fun()`. See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38461391/avoid-pauses-due-to-readline-while-testing) on SO.

Comment: Thanks! Your suggestion works if you require an input inmediatly after calling the function, but in my case needs to be somewhere in the middle of the process. But, its a really smart solution if you need an inmediate input! The link you suggested seems to be helping with my problem (for now). Cheers!